# How do I build an Adobe AIR application using Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: air, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, mxmlc

I have a client with an application that is written in MXML and ActionScript 3 and is deployed as a desktop app using Adobe AIR.  The client would like me to implement automated builds and releases for this application and currently uses Visual Studio Team Services as their build and release management platform.  My question is, what is the best way to use Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) to build an Adobe AIR application?

I am familiar with the amxmlc tool for building AIR applications using the command line but this relies on Java and I cannot find any documentation on how to run a Java-based tool from within VSTS.  Any assistance on this matter would be appreciated.

I understand that Adobe AIR is an older technology but for reasons that are beyond the scope of this question the client does not want to rewrite the application in newer technology at this time.

In addition, alternative build and deployment platforms are out of the question.   I have experience doing something similar using Jenkins however the client would like to stick with VSTS.

Please let me know if you require any additional information to help answer my question.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a private build agent on a machine (can be on your local machine) that have requirement software installed (e.g. JDK, JRE). [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)

You can build the AIR application via amxmlc tool, so you can add [Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/command-line) task to call amxmlc tool to build your project.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to build using a hosted agent but I see no reason why this wouldn't work.  I will need to check with the client to see if this is an option for them but I will accept this answer in the meantime.

Comment: You can check the [Hosted environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/hosted) whether meet the requirements to build AIR application.